# sockjs-node net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I created a brand new tiny webapp with vue cli, so without adding anything, apart from what the empty vue-cli scaffolding brings:

```
(base) marco@pc:~/vueMatters/testproject$ npm run serve


> testproject@0.1.0 serve /home/marco/vueMatters/testproject
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

DONE Compiled successfully in 1409ms 8:14:46 PM


App running at:
- Local: localhost:8080
- Network: 192.168.1.7:8080

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

And got this error message :

```
GET https://localhost/sockjs-node/info?t=1580228998416 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

[image]

node --version
v12.10.0

npm -v
6.13.6

webpack-cli@3.3.10

Ubuntu 18.04.03 Server Edition

last lines of /var/log/nginx/error.log :

```
2020/01/28 18:10:57 [error] 980#980: *34 connect() failed (111: 
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 
66.249.79.119, server: ggc.world, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/robots.txt", host: "ggc.world"

2020/01/28 18:11:37 [error] 980#980: *36 connect() failed (111: 
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.249.79.70,
server: ggc.world, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/robots.txt", host: "www.ggc.world"
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify SSL Certificates in your socket connections.

Here is the reference.

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: where exactly should I specify SSL Certificates in my socket connections?

Comment: Can you please post here some references explaining how to do it?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: @MaxCoplan you are talking about key & cert file?